# Reverse Engineer Android APK to get code?

Tags: android, apk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Getting source code from an APK file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Is it possible to reverse engineer a APK file to get the actual code? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: This is know issue you can see the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file) here

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/ to convert to a JAR file then open it using http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Comment: Is there a way to get the xml files. I get all the code files. Thank you.

Comment: @Vinodtiru the tool I linked can get you the resource files.

Comment: @Abdullah Jibaly i have downloaded dex2jar but i dont know how to use it? Can you please tell me?

Comment: Extract it, copy the .apk to the folder, use CMD to navigate to the folder, use d2j-dex2jar <APK-NAME> to convert to a .jar file

Comment: @Vinodtiru Try DDMS. It shows at least the layouts and the built in Views with their sizes and hierarchies.

Answer (score 5):

Its possible to get the dalvik byte code and the resources decompiled using [Apk Tool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Comment: Is there a way to get the Java code or any human understandable code? Thank you for your time.

Comment: How can I use this tool to get the xml file. I run the cmd "aapt.exe l c:\app.apk". With this i get the list of files. But when I replace the l command to d. I do not get the dump. Basicall I want to get the folder or file with xml from APK. Is this possible?

Comment: I just tested this command and it works `apktool d MyApp.apk ./MyAppDump`

Comment: Sorry. I had done the installation wrong. I am able to get the xml file now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

for Reverse engineering process or getting code from the apk file
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/